# Rails form use token instead of id in action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a standard rails form_for like below, it will return an html form where the action is `/posts/1/comments`. But including the `post.id` is not good for security, instead i want it to use the `post.token` for that record instead.

*Rails form_for*

```
<%= form_for([@post, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

*Html of form_for*

```
<form class="new_comments" id="new_video_marker" action="/posts/1/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="comments[text]" id="comment_text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a token.

```
$ rails generate migration AddTokenToPost post_token:string
```

Modify your post.rb :

```
 # app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :set_post_token
  private
  def set_post_token
    self.post_token = generate_post_token
  end
```

Try this for your form :

```
    <%= form_for([@post, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :token %>
  <%= f.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is how to add a token to the record. Not what i was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

> But including the post.id is not good for security

Who fooled you into thinking that?

This is a classic example of security by obscurity. Sure somebody can't just guess that the url is `/posts/1/comments` but if you're not authorizing the resource properly `/posts/somereallylongtoken/comments` is no more secure. If not UUID's would be magically more secure and there would be no one using auto-incrementing integers for PKs.

You can use single use tokens which are placed in the URL for stuff like user confirmations but thats only because you're sending a link in a email and you're limited to GET. Thats used as a nonce to authorize the user. Not just to obfuscate an ID.